# uploaded images crop with specified width and height with php

Tags: php

On the project that I am working right now I would like all the images that are uploaded to be cropped to the same width and length. First I want to resize all the images to ex. 500px. After they are that size, then I want the height to be cropped to 400. Because some pictures with have 500px width and 500px height, and some will have 500px width and 400px height, so I want those pictures with more height then 400px to be cropped after the resize. I want the 100px cropped section removed from the bottom.

Comment: do you have imagemagick available? it would make light work of this process.

Comment: There's an imagemagick build in extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timthumb, works great for me ;)

https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Comment: I am familiar with timthumb because a lot of wp themes use it, but threw the years  this script suffered a lot of exploits, which makes me think twice.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, you might want to take a look at this:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

OR

http://sanjeevkumarjha.com.np/how-to-resize-and-crop-image/